# I want to clear or initial state when reducer get error in my functional component reactjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux, react-functional-component

Hello reactjs developer.
I was developed an authentication system. When user submit user name and password then state change and loading spinner will render and redux action will fire. If authentication failed action passing data to the reducer and login functional component clear state or set initial state. But I can't understand how to clear or set initial state. Please see my screenshot. I am using redux & functional component.

[`Login page`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igAe.png)
[`Login controller`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4qAl.jpg)
[`Login form`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pd7k2.png)
[`Redux action`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmLnb.png)
[`Redux reducer`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PZlC.png)
[`After submit login loading spinner load`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McE5R.png)

Comment: If authentication failed action passing data to the reducer and login functional component clear state or set initial state. I cant understand this part

Comment: I want to clear state when submission is failed and loading spinner also change. Please see all screenshot. You will find step by step.@tay ferozi thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the `redux state` (i.e. `isAuthenticate`, `user` and `error`) you could `dispatch` a new `action` and in the `reducer` of the that `action`, set new `state` which is the intiial state.

**BUT**

If you are concerned to reset the state of component (i.e. `name`, `password`, `error`, `submitText`, `isLoader` and `count`), what you can do is that
define a new function (e.g. resetState) inside your `Login` component and when you do `dispatch(login(user))`, you can pass a callback like this: `dispatch(login(user, resetState))`. And inside the action

```
export const login = (user, cb) => {
    if() {
        
    } else {
        cb()
    }
}
```

And please copy and paste code here in your next questions, make it a lot easier

Comment: When i use above code `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` will appear
**Login component**
const submitClickHandler = event  => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setUser({
            ...user,
            isLoader: true,
            submitText: 'Sending...'
        });
        dispatch(login(user,resetState)); 
    }
    const resetState = async () => {
        console.log('Action fire from redux action');
    }
**Action**
export const login = (user,cb) => {
    if() {        
    }
    else {
        return cb();
    }
}

Comment: If you want to do asynchrnous tasks inside the action, you have to install `redux-thunk` for that and change the syntax a little bit

Comment: Like this: `export const login = (user, cb) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get("/foo")
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({type: Types.SET_USER, payload});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.response) {
        dispatch({type: Types.SET_USER, payload});
      }
    });
};`

Comment: where & how to use `cb` callback function.

Comment: `cb` is the callback function which you will pass to the action dispatching function `login in this case`. And you will call this `cb` function when your action has been dispatched and it is decided where to sign the user in or not, then you can call `cb` and do whatever you want. In this case you will define `cb` inside you component and in the definition of this function you will clear the state and pass this `cb` to the `login` using dispatch and inside the `if` or `else` block call the `cb` which simply clears the `states`